How to specialize generic protocol in Swift?
I have this sort of piece of code:
public class Metal {}

public protocol Vehicle<M> {
    associatedtype M
    
    var material: [M] { get set }
}

public protocol Tracktor: Vehicle where M == Metal {}

public protocol MetalTracktor: Tracktor {
    var material: [Metal] { get set }
}

Fails to compile the second definition of var material: [Meta] with error:

Cannot override mutable property 'material' of type '[Self.M]' with covariant type '[Metal]'

Why? What's the right way to specialize Tracktor with Metal type?
I would think that Tracktor is already specialized with Metal type, thus the first and second definitions end up being the same and thus should not clash. What am I missing?

I understand that the second definition is redundant, but Swift usually allows redundant definitions. Why doesn't it in this case?

"Why something isn't supported" is not a good question. Does "it will be more work for the Swift compiler team" satisfy you? Can you be more specific about what kind of answer you are looking for?

The question is clearly stated twice: "How to specialize generic protocol in Swift?" and "What's the right way to specialize Tracktor with Metal type?". Generic-specialization is a normal feature that does work properly in other languages, so I'm just asking how to do it in Swift. If the answer is: that it's impossible in Swift, because they failed to implement it properly - then I'm fine with that answer.

The Tracktor protocol already specialises Vehicle. You already did it. I was referring to "Why doesn't it in this case?" at the end of the post, regarding why it doesn't allow you to redeclare the protocol requirement using [Metal] as the type.

The Tracktor protocol already specialises Vehicle. You already did it.
You can write an implementation for Tracktor, and use [Metal] as the type of material.
public class MyTracktor: Tracktor {
    public var material: [Metal] = []
}

Swift first determines whether MyTracktor conforms to Vehicle. It infers that the associated type M is Metal. This implicitly creates a typealias declaration:
typealias M = Metal

Now MyTracktor satisfies both requirements of Vehicle and so conforms to it. It is also the case that MyTracktor.M == Metal, so it conforms to Tracktor.
Writing var material: [Metal] { get set } in MetalTracktor is not allowed, because in the context of MetalTracktor, M and Metal are two different (though related) types. M is an associated type declared in Vehicle, and Metal is a class type declared at the global scope.
Compare this to the MyTracktor class above. In MyTracktor, M is a type alias for Metal - M and Metal are the same type. where M == Metal on the other hand, is stating a requirement of Tracktor, not a typealias.
Swift could technically be designed to be smarter about this, and allow you to write var material: [Metal] { get set } in MetalTracktor, but this is not very useful, since you can just write var material: [M] { get set } to do basically the same thing.
